# How do I get size of "whole" Vim instead of a single window?

Tags: vimscript, functions, window-management, floating-windows

I want to create a floating window, with the width of the entire Vim viewport. I had used `winwidth()` function, but I've encountered problems when windows are split.

I could get a list of windows in a tab, and then try to resolve the full width, but it gonna be a hassle especially when dealing with horizontal splits.

Is there any simpler way function or variable to get those dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the variables `&columns` and `&lines` linked to the options `'columns'` and `'lines'` respectively.